# Why is it saying my variable is undefinded?

Tags: cs50

Hey guys i am new to programming and currently going through CS50 on edx. I am having trouble printing my variable and am getting an error saying it is undefined. I have defined this variable in my for loop on line 22. Can i not print a variable if it is defined in a "for" loop? Below is a screenshot with the error and the variable defined in the link.Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance! [Error in Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKYfY.png)

Comment: Please, post code, not images. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable have scope inside the for loop only, so if you need to print your variable `years`, try to use print inside for loop.

```
for (int years;.....){
   printf(years)
   startsize = ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is undefined because it is only defined in the scope of the for() loop.  Between the {}'s.  You need to move the definition of "int years" outside the for() declaration for it to "live" longer.

Comment: You owe the oracle the manual or textbook you didn't read :)